# Fastest way to deep compare arrays and merge unique objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, zustand

I'm using NextJS with Zustand,  I have one array of objects in my zustand's state:

```
[{a:1, b:2}, {a:2, b:3}]
```

and I have incoming array of objects which have same existing objects + additional unique ones.

```
[{a:2, b3}, {a:4, b:5}, {a:1, b:2}]
```

Problem is that the second array that comes in, comes in a different order. Ideally, I'd like **append** unique items at the end of the previous array. Is looping through the second array with something like say .every() or just a for loop, the fastest way to remove the duplicate items and append new ones? Thanks.

*(If it matters, I'm saving these arrays in zustand's state)*

for loops and .every() - very resource intensive.

Comment: You may be able to use a `Map` or dictionary for this: throw all the items from both arrays into a hash keyed by some string value that captures the unique identify of each item -- duplicates will collide and overwrite. Then convert the final hash back to an array by grabbing `Object.values(hash)` (or use whichever of Map's clunky methods is analogous). Your resulting code should have lowest order time complexity, because you only loop through each array one time. `Object.keys` has fine perf, and `Map` (although unforgivably clunky) is supposed to have even better perf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to implement the same

```js
let dic1 = [{a:1, b:2}, {a:2, b:3}]
let dic2 = [{a:2, b:3}, {a:4, b:5}, {a:1, b:2}]

// You can use a better hash function. Search online for one
function hash(dict) {
 return Object.keys(dict).join("").concat(
      Object.values(dict).join(''))
};

let set = new Set(dic1.map(hash));

dic2.forEach(x=>{if(!set.has(hash(x))) dic1.push(x)});
console.log(dic1);
```